# Sonar-Scanner - Maintaining a list of 'broken' files to skip

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner

I've got a copy of sonar-scanner using a plugin that's still early in its development life. At the moment it seems to have some trouble with some particular files that prevent the scan from completing.

I'd like to build a list of files that should be skipped over as part of the scan process so that I can at least scan the rest of our code. Is there any way I can can have sonar.exclusions read from a file. I'd prefer this because:

- The list is expected to be quite long, and I'm worried about exceeding a length limitation for sonar.exclusions
- It would be ideal to be able to easily add to this list as needed (so a file I can just append to would be preferable).

(And before anyone asks, I'm already working with the vendor to fix the bug in the affected plugin - I just want a way to proceed with implementing SonarQube so I can proceed with getting the analysis pipeline setup while they're working on the fix).

Comment: per default you could use a `sonar-project.properties` and add the configuration properties within that -> if your sonar.exclusions is the last property you could easily append there if you have new files added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so my "solution" is only a partial solution, I still have to add new files manually when I encounter an issue that breaks the plugin.

But it also turns out that sonar.exclusions doesn't appear to have a length limit (or, if it does, it's very generous).